# How to execute commands after post-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

This is my actual `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

Is there any way that I can run a command after the files are already in the folder?

I want to run `composer update`

Comment: What's wrong with adding `cd /var/www/domain.com && composer update` to the existing hook script, right after your `git checkout` line? (Note that I _strongly_ recommend `composer install` instead of `composer update` here, but that's secondary to your question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hook script is simply a shell script (executed by `/bin/sh` in your example). Your script currently has a single command, as defined by the `git checkout` line that you already have.

To do something else after `git checkout`, add it to the script after the git checkout line. Something like this should do:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
cd /var/www/domain.com && composer install
```

Note that I used `composer` *`install`*, not `composer update`. There is a good reason for this.

`composer update` may not result in the exact dependencies that you used during development. For example, if you depend on `some/lib:1.2.*`, you might get version `1.2.1` on your development box and `1.2.2` later on your production machine. Worse yet, maybe you are using something like [`dev-master`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) in which case there could be *major* differences between environments.

From [its documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update):

> In order to get the latest versions of the dependencies and to update the `composer.lock` file, you should use the `update` command.

Compare that with [the documentation for `install`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install) (emphasis mine):

> The `install` command reads the `composer.json` file from the current directory, resolves the dependencies, and installs them into `vendor`.
>
> ```
> php composer.phar install
> ```
>
> *If there is a `composer.lock` file in the current directory, it will use the exact versions from there instead of resolving them. This ensures that everyone using the library will get the same versions of the dependencies.*
>
> If there is no `composer.lock` file, Composer will create one after dependency resolution.

If you are committing your `composer.lock` file [as recommended](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file), `composer install` will give you the same versions on your server as you are using elsewhere.